# trying to see if i can animate the stars moving

Tags: javascript, html, animation

i've been working on trying to animate the stars but i'm not sure how. I've tried using on multiple different techniques but at the end its still not working. it doesn't matter if you move that stars to much i just want them to move. any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 102, 204)";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
ctx.linewidth = 3;

//making the background

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 900);

//making the grass
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(178, 255, 102)";

ctx.fillRect(0, 620, 1000, 280);

// draw the stars
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 153)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(80, 120);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.lineTo(80, 80);
ctx.lineTo(60, 100);
ctx.lineTo(80, 120);
ctx.fill();

 ctx.beginPath(); //star 2
ctx.moveTo(120, 220);
ctx.lineTo(140, 200);
ctx.lineTo(120, 180);
ctx.lineTo(100, 200);
ctx.lineTo(120, 220);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();// star 3
ctx.moveTo(60, 160);
ctx.lineTo(180, 40);
ctx.lineTo(160, 20);
ctx.lineTo(140, 40);
ctx.lineTo(160, 60);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();//star 4
ctx.moveTo(240, 140);
ctx.lineTo(260, 120);
ctx.lineTo(240, 100);
ctx.lineTo(220, 120);
ctx.lineTo(240, 140);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();//star 5
ctx.moveTo(300, 260);
ctx.lineTo(320, 240);
ctx.lineTo(300, 220);
 ctx.lineTo(280, 240);
ctx.lineTo(300, 260);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();//star 6
ctx.moveTo(380, 180);
ctx.lineTo(400, 160);
ctx.lineTo(380, 140);
ctx.lineTo(360, 160);
ctx.lineTo(380, 180);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();//star 7
ctx.moveTo(460, 80);
ctx.lineTo(480, 60);
ctx.lineTo(460, 40);
ctx.lineTo(440, 60);
ctx.lineTo(460, 80);
 ctx.fill();

 ctx.beginPath();//star 8 
 ctx.moveTo(520, 160);
 ctx.lineTo(540, 140);
 ctx.lineTo(520, 120);
 ctx.lineTo(500, 140);
 ctx.lineTo(520, 160);
 ctx.fill();


 ctx.beginPath();//star 9
ctx.moveTo(620, 60);
ctx.lineTo(640, 40);
ctx.lineTo(620, 20);
ctx.lineTo(600, 40);
ctx.lineTo(620, 60);
ctx.fill();


ctx.beginPath();//star 10
ctx.moveTo(660, 180);
ctx.lineTo(680, 160);
ctx.lineTo(660, 140);
ctx.lineTo(640, 160);
ctx.lineTo(660, 180);
ctx.fill();


ctx.beginPath();//star 11 
ctx.moveTo(600, 240);
ctx.lineTo(620, 220);
ctx.lineTo(600, 200);
ctx.lineTo(580, 220);
ctx.lineTo(600, 240);
ctx.fill();


ctx.beginPath();//star 12 
ctx.moveTo(740, 80);
ctx.lineTo(760, 60);
ctx.lineTo(740, 40);
ctx.lineTo(720, 60);
ctx.lineTo(740, 80);
ctx.fill();


ctx.beginPath();//star 13 
ctx.moveTo(820, 160);
ctx.lineTo(840, 140);
ctx.lineTo(820, 120);
ctx.lineTo(800, 140);
ctx.lineTo(820, 160);
ctx.fill();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you at least looked for a pen? https://codepen.io/tag/stars/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var i = 0;
var speed = 500;

var drawStar = function (x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(80 + x, 120 + y);
  ctx.lineTo(100 + x, 100 + y);
  ctx.lineTo(80 + x, 80 + y);
  ctx.lineTo(60 + x, 100 + y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
};

var render = function () {
  i += 1;
  var offset = i % speed; // calculate how much the stars moved

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 102, 204)";

  //making the background
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);

  //making the grass
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(178, 255, 102)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 200, 400, 100);

  // draw the stars
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 153)";
  drawStar(offset, 0);
  drawStar(offset + 100, 50);
  drawStar(offset + 160, 20);
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(render); // call render again in about 33ms
};

render(); // call render for the first time
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: the offset is not defined? -neckbeard juinor